# How to pass the values of a tbl_df column as choices in a shiny widget?

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I am trying to build some widgets dynamically, by using dplyr to connect to a database and then passing the unique values from certain columns as choices in the different widgets.
To make the code reproducible, I give an example where I transform the built-in vector 'state.abb' in a tbl_df of 1 column, which I guess should work as if the tbl were hosted remotely.

My **ui.R** file looks like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Test"),

  fluidRow(

  #this part works
    column(4,
    checkboxGroupInput('tbl1', '',
                       state.abb, 
                       selected = state.abb)
    ),

    #this doesn't work
    column(4,
           checkboxGroupInput('tbl2', '',
                              tbl_df(as.data.frame(state.abb)), 
                              selected = tbl_df(as.data.frame(state.abb)))
    )


    ))
  )
```

While my **server.R** is empty

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {      

})
```

When I run the app, I see the first checklist, but the second is not displayed since `tbl_df(as.data.frame(state.abb))` is not a vector.

What would be the correct approach to pass values from a dplyr table into shiny widget functions? Is that even recommendable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be simple

```
tbl_df(as.data.frame(state.abb))[[1]]
```